# Google fusion table update latency

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have created a Google fusion table which I display on a web page. I have written VB.net code to query my fusion table. The code executes correctly, but the query results lag behind edits that have been manually made to the fusion table on the web page. Obviously, I need my VB.net query data to return the data exactly as it is displayed in my fusion table. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this delay? It appears that if I wait for 30 seconds to query the fusion table, the results match what is displayed. This delay appears to ONLY occur after the first fusion table edit on the web page, i.e., I can edit one cell in the fusion table and immediately get query results that match the displayed values. This feels like a configuration issue???

Comment: Please provide your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Originally, I was using the following to query my fusion table:

Dim FTqueryRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(FTqueryURL)

Dim FTqueryResponse As WebResponse = FTqueryRequest.GetResponse()

Dim queryResponsestrmRdr As New StreamReader(FTqueryResponse.GetResponseStream(), True)

When I switched to using Google fusiontablesservice, the query results are identical to what is displayed on the fusion table web page.

Dim mySQLquery = myFusionTablesService.Query.SqlGet("SELECT * FROM " & c_FusionTable_ID).Execute